# Can anyone beat this jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been running some tests to see if I can find an efficient selector for controls prefixed with the id of parent controls in Asp.Net

I've been looking for this as I was to be able to select Asp controls from external javascript files (I'm fed up of using ClientID).

To test I set up a page with 150 textboxes all with the cssclass "speedy" and an individual id and ran the following code to select the 107th textbox.

```
function testclientInput() {

    var iterations = 100;
    var totalTime = 0;

    // Record the starting time, in UTC milliseconds.
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    // Repeat the test the specified number of iterations.
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        // Execute the selector. The result does not need
        // to be used or assigned to determine how long 
        // the selector itself takes to run.

        // All tests done in ie6, ie7, ie8, ie9beta, firefox3.6, opera11 & chrome8

        // slowest
        // $('input.speedy[id$=_TextBox107]');

        // Quick but only useful if you know the index.
        //$($('input.speedy')[106]);

        //$('[id$=_TextBox107]:first');

        //$('input[id$=_TextBox107]');

        //$.clientID("TextBox107");

        //$('[id$=_TextBox107]');

        //$('input[id$=_TextBox107]:first');

        //$($('[id$=_TextBox107]')[0]);

       // Fastest
       //$($('input[id$=_TextBox107]')[0]);
    }

    // Record the ending time, in UTC milliseconds.
    var end = new Date().getTime();

    // Determine how many milliseconds elapsed
    totalTime = (end - start);

    // Report the average time taken by one iteration.
    alert(totalTime / iterations);

};
```

This is the best I have come up with. `$($('input[id$=_TextBox107]')[0]);`. The results have been surprising.... I expected using the `:first` selector to match my version but it reported much slower results.

Can anyone think of a way to optimize this?

Comment: Sorry, but why can't you use `document.getElementById('_TextBox107')`? IDs should be unique anyway

Comment: @Harmen: He's using the *attribute ends with* selector, so `_TextBox107` is just the last part of the ID.

Comment: @Harmen: Because asp controls are prefixed by their parent id. I do state this in my question.

Comment: In my opinion it's a bad idea to do this because MS could (and has) changed the way that control ids get generated.  So far, you can guarantee that no matter version of .Net is used, the ids will end with _TextBox107, but you can't guarantee that .Net 4.1 will still do this.  Additionally, your test assumes no cacheing.  Meaning, :first might be slower over 1000 iterations, but maybe it doesn't cache, and the last 999 iterations you ran with jQuery are cached.

Comment: @Matt - I'm not planning to use the selector for everything. I have lots of 2.0 / 3.5 sites that the correct selector could help with. One  site specifically. The test is simple I know but it should give me a general indicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend on the browser.

This version:

```
$('input[id$=_TextBox107]')
```

...is a valid `querySelectorAll` selector, so any browser that implements it will be very fast.

If you use the `:first` selector, you're using something that is not a valid CSS selector, so it defaults to Sizzle's javascript based selector engine, and will be much slower.

If performance is crucial, then don't use jQuery for this. You can just use `document.getElementsByTagName()`, and filter the one(s) you want, if the browser doesn't support `querySelectorAll`.

```
var match;
if( !document.querySelectorAll ) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for( var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if( /_TextBox107/.test( inputs[i].id ) ) {
            var match = $(inputs[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    match = $( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[id$=_TextBox107]' )[0] );
}
```

Comment: @James: Awesome. Glad to hear it helped. :o)

Comment: ...also, I'd add that a small improvement to the regex would be to add the `$` at the end `if( /_TextBox107$/.test( inputs[i].id ) )`, or perhaps don't use a regex at all, but use `indexOf()` instead. `if( inputs[i].id.indexOf('_TextBox107') != -1 )`. This may perform a little better, and I doubt you'll get any false-positives with that specific of a string.

Comment: @Patrick: You couldn't write a version that accepts parameters in place of input and TextBox107 could you? I keep getting undetermined string errors. it's driving me crazy!

Comment: @James: Sure. Can you give me what you have so far, so I can build on that. Would be great if you'd make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8wsQ/) that I can work off of.

Comment: @Patrick: Cheers! here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/q8wsQ/1/ I'll pre-emptively mark you down as the answer anyway :)

Comment: @James: Thanks for the "accept". :o) I'm going to give you two versions. [Here's the first](http://jsfiddle.net/q8wsQ/2/) where I changed the regex to `new RegExp('_' + id).test(inputs[i].id)`. This is required when incorporating a variable. The second is forthcoming...

Comment: [...here's the second](http://jsfiddle.net/q8wsQ/3/) where I used `.indexOf()`. `inputs[i].id.indexOf('_' + id) != -1` You may want to performance test the two. The `.indexOf()` may perform a little better in some browsers.

Comment: Wizzard! Thank you so much for that.You've really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt do any exhaustive testing but I was getting results using your "slowest" selector that were more or less as fast as your "fastest" selector...Some of the other options were noticeably slower though. However, I only tested using IE8...

My method of choice before reading this was...

```
$("[id$='_TextBox107']")
```

which performed somewhat slower that your "fastest" but was by far not the worst choice. I may have to do some more testing and rethink my choice.

Comment: @ Stephen: It really depend on the browser. ie6 and 7 are pretty slow when working with classes.